# How to get each value from a particular mysql table by using datatable without using a for or foreach loop in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to get each value from mysql table by using `DataTable` without using a loop. Here I have two `DataTables`, I want to increment `dtfilmsngtemp` and need to get values, i.e if `dtsnglyric` have `id=2`, Then I need to have get `id=2` in `dtfilmsngtemp`, So in general I need to get he same 'id's' from two `DataTables`. First of all row id is 1 in  `dtsnglyric` and `dtfilmsngtemp`, But `dtsnglyric` is incremented to 2, According to my requirement `dtfilmsngtemp` is also need to become 2. How it is possible?

```
DataTable dtsnglyric = GetAllsnglyrctmp();
DataTable dtfilmsngtemp = GetAllfilmsngtemp();
foreach (DataRow drow1 in dtsnglyric.Rows)
{
      string lyrsct = drow1["lyricist"].ToString();
      string sngrs = drow1["singers"].ToString();

      foreach (DataRow drow in dtfilmsngtemp.Rows)
      {
         string lid = drow["lyric_id"].ToString();
         string fid = drow["film_id"].ToString();
      }
}
```

Comment: Your variable names are incredibly hard to understand, it makes it almost impossible to read the question. Maybe consider changing them from `dtsnglyric` to `dtSingerLyric`, etc.. at least for your future maintainers....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataRow[] dr1 = null;
        DataRow[] dr2 = null;
        string value1 = string.Empty;
        string value2 = string.Empty;

        dt1.Columns.Add("A");
        dt1.Columns.Add("B");

        dt2.Columns.Add("A");
        dt2.Columns.Add("B");

        // Add to DataTable
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dt1.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), (i + 1).ToString());
            dt2.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), (i + 2).ToString());
        }

        // Find By Select Example i want to take dt1 Column A = 2 and dt2 Column A = 9
        dr1 = dt1.Select("A=2"); // Select statement >>> Column = Value
        dr2 = dt2.Select("A=9");

        // Check & Get B Value
        if (dr1 != null && dr1.Length == 1) value1 = dr1[0]["B"] + "";
        if (dr2 != null && dr2.Length == 1) value2 = dr2[0]["B"] + "";

        Response.Write(value1 + ":" + value2);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an inner join operation. Can't you do it in the SQL query? `DataTable` doesn't support that, but you can do it with LINQ. However, note that it will take O(n^2) time and shouldn't be used for big tables:

```
var results = from table1 in dtsnglyric.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in dtfilmsngtemp.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["lyricist"] equals (int)table2["lyric_id"]
             select new
             {
                 lyricist= (int)table1["lyricist"],
                 lyric_id= (int)table2["lyric_id"],
                 film_id= (int)table2["film_id"],
                 singers = (int)table1["singers"]
             };
```